# Position given to element immediately resets

Tags: javascript, html, css

The Trexwrapper is a container for the trex image and trex name. I did this so I could move it together. My idea was to scroll down and make the Trexwrapper appear in my screen. The function works. But when I scrolled down it immediately resets the positioning I applied with that animation keyframe. I want this position to stay.

```js
let TRex = document.querySelector("#TRex-Wrapper");

window.addEventListener("scroll", function(e) {
  if (window.pageYOffset > 500) {
    TRex.classList.add("TrexMove");
  }

  if (window.pageYOffset < 200) {
    TRex.classList.remove("TrexMove");
  }
});
```

```css
#TRex-Wrapper {
  width: 660px;
  height: 350px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(750px); /*Initial Position of the Treximage + Trexname*/
}

.TrexMove {
  animation: TrexAppearance 1s;
}

@keyframes TrexAppearance {
  0% {}
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0); /*The new position i gave the trexwrapper (Trex + trexname) which immediatly resets right after the animation played out*/
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="TRex-Wrapper">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" alt="Tyrannosaurus Rex" id="TyrannosaurusRex">
  
  <p id="T-rexP">Tyrannosaurus Rex</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I haven't been able to demonstrate what you describe. The class is never added. Does the demo work for you?

Comment: Your snippet does not seem to allow any scrolling. However, are you looking for animation-fill-mode: forwards?

Comment: @isherwood Sry, i am new here. You're talking about the code snippet right? Its not showing anything simply because it doesnt know what img to put. But i was kind of hoping people would understand my issue and the fix simply by looking at the code. How to help clarify my issue further?

Comment: I don't understand. Your code should apply a class when the page scrolls. I don't see it doing that.

Comment: @AHaworth Yes, thank you. I believe you're correct. And yes true, with the code ive shown you above, you can't tell that scrolling is possible. But in my html i made it work. Thanks for the help, this is all i need for now. Thanks aswell for your effort isherwood